# Optional search with regular expression

Tags: c++, regex

I have a string "minDate=2013-12-01T08:00:00Z&maxDate=2014-01-01T12:00:00Z"
So i need the min and max date in output. The Regex which i use is 
"minDate=(.*?)(?:maxDate=)(.*)"

I get the correct output :

```
Full match  `minDate=2013-12-01T08:00:00Z&amp;maxDate=2014-01-01T12:00:00Z`  
Group 1.    `2013-12-01T08:00:00Z;`  
Group 2.    `2014-01-01T12:00:00Z`
```

Now the problem is "minDate" or "maxDate" can be optional. Means the input can be either:

```
minDate=2013-12-01T08:00:00Z&amp;maxDate=2014-01-01T12:00:00Z
```

or

```
minDate=2013-12-01T08:00:00Z
```

or

```
maxDate=2014-01-01T12:00:00Z
```

What will be the Regex for this so that:

for first input i should get Group 1 '2013-12-01T08:00:00Z' and Group 2 as '2014-01-01T12:00:00Z'
and for second input i should get Group1 '2013-12-01T08:00:00Z'
and for third input i should get Group1 '2014-01-01T12:00:00Z'

Comment: Try `\D+=(\d+)(?:;\D+=(\d+))?`

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer revo but I have edited the question since i had missed initially some points

Comment: What about `\D+=([^&]+)(?:\D+=([^&]+))?`? See in action https://regex101.com/r/ULJ3nt/2

Comment: Maybe you can approach it a bit differently, see [this demo](https://ideone.com/cnyfmO).

Comment: Thanks revo and Wiktor..Both answer made me learn new approach to solve a regex problem..

Answer (score 1):

You may match and capture `minDate` or `maxDate` into Group 1 and the datetime value into Group 2, and then you can assign the variables in your program as needed:

```
std::string maxDate = "";
std::string minDate = "";
std::regex r("(min|max)Date=([0-9-]+T[0-9A-Z:]+)");
std::string s = "minDate=2013-12-01T08:00:00Z&amp;maxDate=2014-01-01T12:00:00Z";
for(std::sregex_iterator i = std::sregex_iterator(s.begin(), s.end(), r);
    i != std::sregex_iterator();
    ++i)
{
    std::smatch m = *i;
    if (m[1].str()=="min") {
        minDate = m[2].str();
        std::cout << "Min date: " << minDate << endl;
    } else {
        maxDate = m[2].str();
        std::cout << "Max date: " << maxDate << endl;
    }
}
```

See the [C++ demo](https://ideone.com/K1gwvX)

Output:

```
Min date: 2013-12-01T08:00:00Z
Max date: 2014-01-01T12:00:00Z
```

**Pattern details**

- `(min|max)` - Capturing group 1 (this value is checked against): either `min` or `max`
- `Date=` - a literal string `Date=`
- `([0-9-]+T[0-9A-Z:]+)` - Capturing group 2 (its value is the result): one or more digits or/and `-`, then `T`, then one or more uppercase ASCII letters, digits or/and `:`.